# Test for convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convergence of a series involving $x^\sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271138/convergence-of-a-series-involving-x-sqrtn)

Test for convergence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}$$
My first thought was to use the ratio test but it's inconclusive since it yields $1$.
Are there some easy means to test the sum for convergence? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n>2^{10}$, we have that $$\sqrt{n}\geq 2\log_2(n),$$  and so for $n>2^{10}$ $$2^{\sqrt{n}}\geq n^2.$$  Now try using the comparison test.

Comment: This is definitely a very good option.

Comment: $n \geqslant 2^8$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

A quick answer can be given by comparison with the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}1/n^2$.

Check that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n^2 /2^\sqrt{n}=0$.

Deduce that there is a positive constant $K$ such that $\frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{K}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Conclude by comparison.

Answer (score 6):

$$2^{-\sqrt n}\leqslant\int_{n-1}^n\exp(-\sqrt x\log 2).$$
The integral $\int_1^{+\infty}\exp(-\sqrt x\log 2)dx$ is convergent, using the substitution $s=\sqrt x$. We conclude by [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), after having checked we can use it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled with a higher order ratio test, [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test). 
Let $a_n = 1/2^{\sqrt{n}}$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
n\left(\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| - 1\right) 
&=& n\left(2^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}} - 1\right) \\
&<& n\left(2^{-1/(2\sqrt{n+1})}-1\right) \\
&<& -\frac{n}{4\sqrt{n+1}}\log 2.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
In the second to last line we use the square root inequality 
$\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1} < -1/(2\sqrt{n+1})$ for $n\ge 0$. 
In the last line we use the exponential inequality 
$e^{-x} < 1-x/2$ for $0<x<2+W(-2/e^2) = 1.59362\cdots$. 
Now we need only show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 
-\frac{n}{4\sqrt{n+1}}\log 2 < -1.$$

Comment: Raabe's test might be an option. (+1) Thanks oen!

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

So, you could use the comparison test, that one would yield results.