# $\text{Sup}\{x\geq0:\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt n}<\infty \}$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convergence of a series involving $x^\sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271138/convergence-of-a-series-involving-x-sqrtn)

How to find $\text{Sup}\{x\geq0:\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt n}<\infty \}?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \geq 1$, the terms don't go to zero so the series diverges. When $0 \leq x < 1$ we can write
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = k^2}^{(k+1)^2 - 1}x^{\sqrt n}$$
In the inner sum, there are $2k + 1$ terms, each of which is bounded by $x^{\sqrt{k^2}} = x^k$, since $x^{\sqrt{n}}$ decreases in $n$ when $0 \leq x < 1$. Hence the sum is bounded by
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(2k+1)x^k$$
This can readily be shown to be convergent using the ratio or root test, so we have convergence when
$0 \leq x < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\ge 1$, this series diverges obviously. If $0\le x<1$, by Cauchy consendation test, this series converges iff 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{\sqrt{2}^n}$$
converges. And 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n x^{\sqrt{2}^n}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}2x^{\frac{\sqrt{2}^n}{n}}=0.$$
So by root test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{\sqrt{2}^n}$ converges.

Comment: This is not what is asked: OP would like to know for what values of $x$ the sum does converge.

Comment: @Martijn edited.

Comment: @tetori: I see. Seems to be correct.

Comment: @mrf corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the set : $$X=\{x \geq 0 / \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x^{\sqrt n} < +\infty \}$$
We have : $X = [0,1[$. and  $\sup(X)=1$.
In fact : 
If $x \geq 1$ the serie $\sum x^{\sqrt n} $ diverges since  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty} x^{ \sqrt n} \neq 0$ (the limit is $1$ if $x=1$  and  $+\infty$ if $x > 1$ )

If $x=0$ the sum is $0$.

If $0 < x < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$  there  is  a  unique  $p_n \in \mathbb N$  such that $p_n \leq  \sqrt n  < p_n+1$ then $x^{\sqrt n} \leq x^{p_n}$ and then we have for all $n \in {\mathbb N}^*$ : $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} x^{\sqrt n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^N x^{p_n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{p_N} x^n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} $$